# Rest client Jersey 2

Tags: java, rest, maven, jersey

Trying to create a restful clint in Java with Jersey2.
There is 2 problem with this code:
1. Prety slow needs more than 2 seconds
2. Something is wrong with the data binding, only 2/6 data is binded well

Main Java:

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

public class JerseyTestClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget webTarget = client.target("https://wtfismyip.com/json");
        Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        Response response = invocationBuilder.get();
        WtfIsMyConfig wtfIsMyConfig = response.readEntity(WtfIsMyConfig.class);

        System.out.println(response);
        System.out.println(wtfIsMyConfig);
    }

}
```

Model

```
public class WtfIsMyConfig implements Serializable {

    private String YourIPAddress;
    private String YourLocation;
    private String YourHostname;
    private String YourISP;
    private String YourTorExit;
    private String YourCountryCode;

    public WtfIsMyConfig() {
    }
    //getters setters
}
```

Pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Output console:

```
InboundJaxrsResponse{context=ClientResponse{method=GET, uri=https://wtfismyip.com/json, status=200, reason=OK}}
WtfIsMyConfig{YourIPAddress='192.168.0.0', YourLocation='null', YourHostname='192-168-0-0.pool.digikabel.hu', YourISP='null', YourTorExit='null', YourCountryCode='null'}

Process finished with exit code 0
Compilation completed successfully with 3 warnings in 2s 500ms
```

Requested Output:

```
{
   "YourIPAddress": "192.168.0.0",
   "YourLocation": "XXX, 18, Hungary",
   "YourHostname": "192-168-0-0.pool.digikabel.hu",
   "YourISP": "DIGI Tavkozlesi es Szolgaltato Kft.",
   "YourTorExit": "false",
   "YourCountryCode": "HU"
}
```

Comment: Although the output is a bit rude, it works for me and well under 2 secs. Perhaps an issue with your Internet connection?

Comment: Where are you timing the request? The result you posted is about compilation time.

Comment: _"Although the output is a bit rude"_ - Please edit it so it is not.

Comment: I have no idea what is happend, but now I tried again and it works. The null values are gone. Maybe it was some network error, anyway thank you for helping.